# if condition depending on existence

Tags: stata

My dataset looks like this:

```
firm_id year    total_workers
   1    1975    614
   1    1976    68
   1    1977    708
   1    1978    18
   1    1979    536
   3    1975    154
   3    1976    59
   3    1977    115
   3    1978    40
   3    1979    380
   4    1975    49
   4    1976    42
   4    1977    53
   4    1978    54
   4    1979    34
   5    1975    254
   5    1976    1115
```

and so on...

I'd like Stata to display all `firm_id`s and the corresponding `year` in which the value of `total_workers` is 10 times larger than the value of `total_workers` in another `year` but within the same `firm_id`. For example, concerning `firm_id == 1`, Stata should display `firm_id ==1` and `year == 1977` (it doesn't have to be displayed exactly in this way) since in 1977 `total_workers` was more than 10 times larger than `total_workers` in 1976.

Since the command `display` doesn't seem to work in this context, I used the command `tab` which is a more or less unsatisfactory substitute. But nevertheless my overall command doesn't work. It looks like this and is a first try....:

```
  by firm_id: tab firm_id year if total_workers >10*total_workers
```

As you can see, the `if` condition is not specified in the way it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you only want to compare consecutive years (by firm) which can be done like this:

```
clear all
set more off

input firm_id year total_workers
    1 1975 614
    1 1976 68
    1 1977 708
    1 1978 18
    1 1979 536
    3 1975 154
    3 1976 59
    3 1977 115
    3 1978 40
    3 1979 380
    4 1975 49
    4 1976 42
    4 1977 53
    4 1978 54
    4 1979 34
    5 1975 254
    5 1976 1115
end

sort firm_id year // important
list, sepby(firm_id)

by firm_id: gen flag = (total_workers[_n] > 10*total_workers[_n-1])
list if flag == 1
```

The important points are the `sort` and the use of [subscripting](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?subscripting).

To make it one line shorter, you can incorporate the `sort` into the main instruction like this:

```
bysort firm_id (year): gen flag = (total_workers[_n] > 10*total_workers[_n-1])
```

The reason your code doesn't work is that Stata evaluates it on the dataset
line by line (i.e. observation by observation from top to bottom) - I appreciate 
any correction if there's an error here -.
You are asking Stata
to tabulate only if one observed instance of the variable is larger than itself multiplied by 10
which is impossible (i.e. always false). See the output of the following:

```
bysort firm_id (year): gen flag = 1 if total_workers > 10*total_workers
```

Using subscripts explicitly, the previous line is equivalent to

```
bysort firm_id (year): gen flag = 1 if total_workers[_n] > 10*total_workers[_n]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This is what I wanted. How do I have to change the code if I also want to cover the case when **total_workers[_n-1] > 10*total_workers[_n]**?

Comment: You're welcome. You can be even more explicit and describe "exactly" what you seek. This can take more time in terms of posting/editing your question, but in the long-run, it is more efficient for everyone.

Comment: I'm sorry for having been vague.

Comment: If you are interested in adding another condition you can use logical operators. Run `help operators` to read on them. I think you want an "or" so it could be something like `if condition1 | condition2`. Notice the `|` is the mentioned operator in Stata.